# How to run code at a certain time using LocalNotification iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, notifications

I am building an app that sends a notification at a certain time and I need it to run some code at that time when the app is closed. Currently I have no problem showing the notification even when the app is closed with UILocalNotification. How am I able to make the notification run a function when it fires (not when the user taps on the notification) even when the app is closed?

I'm using Xamarin.iOS if that helps, but even non-xamarin answers are welcome.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "when the app is closed".  Do you mean when it is not running, or do you mean when it is in background?

Comment: @Smartcat When the app is completely closed, not in background

Answer (score 0):

UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate doesn't offer a way for the backgrounded app to be told when a user received a notification.  It only calls your backgrounded app if the user interacts with the notification (including if they simply dismiss it).

Now there may be other ways to achieve what you want.  Check out [PushKit_SilentPushNotification](https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification) and let us know if it worked out for you. It claims to even work when your app is killed. (I found this via a quick search today, so there are likely other solutions out there too - no idea if Apple would approve or not but I'd certainly be concerned).